# Is there a way to specifically set values to an LED pin using the library?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio

My friend is using the GPIO library; .NET IoT 1.3

He was trying to control the brightness/strength of the LED, but the library seems to only have a way to turn the LEDs on and off.

Here is some code I've quickly sprung up as to show what I mean

```
using System;
using System.Device.Gpio;
using System.Threading;

int pin = 17;
using var controller = new GpioController();
controller.OpenPin(pin, PinMode.Output);
controller.Write(pin, PinValue.High)
```

Whereas, PinValue, according to the documentation has the values "High" and "Low". But seemingly no way to adjust it specifically.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.gpio.pinvalue?view=iot-dotnet-1.3

Now, in Python it's very simple to control LED brightness; using the GPIO Zero library:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from signal import pause

led = LED(17)

led.value = 0.5

pause()
```

Is there any way, without modifying memory, to achieve this using the given .NET Library?

Comment: No, a GPIO can either be ON or OFF. Nothing in between. What gpiozero does, when you set the led value 0.5, is using [Pulse Width Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) ie basically, turning the led on and of at a certain frequency.

Comment: See also the docs of gpizero on [led brightness](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#led-with-variable-brightness)  If you want the same behaviour in .net you'll either need to implement pwm yourself or find a library that has it included.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is interesting because all 17 of the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi are **digital** and not **analogue**. Which means they can only send down 2 values.  A `zero` or a `one`.

I have been looking at the C# implementaion and you are right in that the class `GpioPinValue` is an `enum` with only 2 options so when you call write to write to a port you can only write `High (1)` or `Low (0)`.

**.NET Core IoT Library**

I even took a look at Microsofts new IoT library for .NET Core that can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/iot

Looking at the source code for the [GpioController.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/main/src/System.Device.Gpio/System/Device/Gpio/GpioController.cs) class this new framework takes in a [PinValue.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/main/src/System.Device.Gpio/System/Device/Gpio/PinValue.cs) object that you can use to write too.

```
public virtual void Write(int pinNumber, PinValue value)
```

But even in the new code, the `PinValue` object has a `private byte` field which you dont have access to and a `private constructor`.  It also declares 2 public fields.  1 for Low and 1 for high as you can see here:

```
public readonly struct PinValue : IEquatable<PinValue>
{
    // This isn't bool so the struct will retain blittable. This
    // allows arrays of PinValue and structs that contain PinValue to
    // be stack allocated.
    private readonly byte _value;

    private PinValue(byte value) => _value = value;

    /// <summary>
    /// The value of the pin is high.
    /// </summary>
    public static PinValue High => new PinValue(1);

    /// <summary>
    /// The value of the pin is low.
    /// </summary>
    public static PinValue Low => new PinValue(0);
```

So on the face of it, I cant see how you can write a value between 0 and 1 (eg 0.5) to one of those GPIO ports.

If that Python code sample actually works on a Raspberry Pi it would be interesting to see if anyone can explain what its doing!

Comment: gpizero uses [Pulse-Width-Modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation) to control the [led brightness](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#led-with-variable-brightness)

Comment: Hi @derpirscher.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but not with GPIO. You need a PWM pin and a PWM object. Unlike gpizero, Iot does not automatically switch to PWM if you write a value other than 0 or 1. The Raspberry Pi has only 2 PWM channels, so you can only control 2 LEDs this way. The pins are usually (logical) 12 and 13, but can be switched to 18 and 19.

[Here is a link describing the usage of PWM with the IOT library.](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/main/Documentation/raspi-pwm.md)

Very simplistic example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello PWM!");
            var pwm = PwmChannel.Create(0, 0, 400, 0.5);
            pwm.Start();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

This will set the led on pin 12 to 50% brightness, given the following entry in /boot/config.txt:

```
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=12,func=4,pin2=13,func2=4
```